# Simulate the user clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a link to be clicked when a key is pressed, I cooked up this jQuery:

```
   $('form#form1').bind("keypress", function(e){
        if(e.keycode == 13 || e.keyChar == 13 || e.which == 13){
        $('.LoginBoxButton a').click();
        }   
    });
```

It doesn't work, and I've read the following explaining why:

> It's important to remember that
>   click() will not trigger the default
>   behavior on a link, even if nothing
>   else is preventing it. So you can't
>   use click() by itself to simulate the
>   user clicking on a link and being
>   taken to another url.

But how DO you simulate the user clicking on a link and being taken to another url?

Comment: .click() **does** trigger the default behaviour of a link (really there's nothing else it *can* do), but it doesn't trigger any of the event handlers attached to the link element

Comment: You should have done this, $('.LoginBoxButton a').trigger('click');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may go about like this:

```
$('form#form1').bind("keypress", function(e){
    if(e.keycode == 13 || e.keyChar == 13 || e.which == 13){
      document.location.href = $('.LoginBoxButton a').attr('href');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> But how DO you simulate the user clicking on a link and being taken to another url?

These are two different things:

The first, simulate user clicking, is a quite low-level task. I'd choke to a browser that allowed it without limits.

The second, taking the user to another url, is as easy as assigning the url you want to `document.location.href`.

So, instead of

```
$('.LoginBoxButton a').click();
```

use

```
document.location.href = $('.LoginBoxButton a').attr('href');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To simulate a click, do this, $('.LoginBoxButton a').trigger('click');

Answer (score 1):

First of all [jQuery's Event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) *normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`* - so you don't have to check `keyCode`/`charCode`.
Secondly decide whether you want to simulate user click on element or just redirect to other location, because there is a huge difference between one and the second. While the last one just redirect the first one first execute all connected `mousedown`/`mouseup`/`click` (in given order) events. Also if `click` event will return `false` redirection should be blocked.

So the code for the first situation is already given, but here's the code for true simulation:

```
<a href="test.html">LsINK</a>
<span>ROBOT</span>

$("a").mousedown(function() { alert("mousedown"); })
      .mouseup(function() { alert("mouseup"); })
      .click(function() { alert("click"); return false; });

$("span").click(function() {
    if (false !== $("a").mousedown().mouseup().triggerHandler("click")) {
        alert("Redirect to: " + $("a").attr("href"));
        //window.location.href = $("a").attr("href");
    }
});
```